# What are the consequences of declaring the New() entry point as private?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a basic WinForm project where the startup form is declared as `Public Sub New()`.
ReSharper is telling me that my New() constructor can be made private. What are the consequences of doing so? Does this change how my form loads? Or does it just make it so the form can't be created from another project?

I'm having trouble getting specific information about making an entry point private. Logically, I would think that if the entry point was private then the form would never load because there is no way to construct it.

Comment: You can't instantiate a class which has a private constructor. In C#/C++ I've used this technique to implement [singletons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#C#_implementation).

Comment: A private constructor is normal in a class that has a factory method.  In VB.NET, any class derived from Form in fact *does* have such a method.  It implements the dreaded default instance.  Code like `Form2.Show()` is valid in VB.NET, Resharper can't see the constructor being used.  Following the Resharper advice however will make that statement invalid.

Comment: Thanks Hans. So when my application is run from the main executable is the default instance of the form loaded?

Comment: Roughly, the first instance that is created becomes the default instance.

Comment: Except in testing it makes it so my form never loads, default or not. If I follow the advice of ReSharper the whole project is borked.

Comment: As I warned you about, this is a Resharper bug.  Consider [filing a bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/RSRP).  But beware that it is pretty hard to fix since Resharper just can't see enough of the My.Forms implementation code, so don't expect miracle cures.  Well, it is a dreaded feature indeed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one more consequence: Your form will disappear from My.Forms collection and impliciting creating/using/opening of this form will not be possible. You'll have to create your own instance by yourself if you were using My.Forms (event without explicitly calling My.Forms. collection).

Other consequences has already been mentioned in other answers and comments:

- you can't instantiate this class from outside, you'll need another constructor with parameters or shared method to create instance
- you can't inherit this class and create instance, inherited class would have to call other constructor with parameters, if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET if you explicitly declare a constructor as private, you cannot create an instance of the form:

```
Private Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
End Sub
```

But if don't set access modifier for `Sub New`, it will be public:

```
Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
End Sub
```

Comment: If resharper suggests removing `Public` keyword, you can follow it without any problem, but if it suggests adding `Private`, if you follow that, you cannot create an instance of the form.

Comment: Reza, this is the part that doesn't make sense. Why would it tell me to do that? It causes my project to fail on load.

Comment: If it's really suggesting to make it explicitly `Private`, it's a *wrong* suggestion. Ignore it.

Comment: That is the answer I was looking for. Just making sure I was correct about that.